# In linux I want to compare yesterday's file to today's file getting only changes from today as the output, ignoring some fields

Tags: linux, bash, compare, unique, diff

I have 2 pipe delimited files. yesterday.txt and today.txt

yesterday.txt:

```
1234|12|Bill|Blatt|programmer
3243|34|Bill|Blatt|dentist
98734|25|Jack|Blatt|programmer
748567|31|Mark|Spark|magician
```

today.txt

```
123|12|Bill|Blatt|programmer
3243|4|Bill|Blatt|dentist
934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
```

I would like to compare the 2 files while ignoring the first 2 fields and output any lines unique to the second file (today.txt), but I want the full lines even though the comparison is omitting the first 2 fields.
So in the case above the output would be:

new_today.txt

```
934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
```

I tried to accomplish using this:

```
sort <(cut -d"|" -f3- yesterday.txt) <(cut -d"|" -f3- yesterday.txt) <(cut -d"|" -f3- today.txt) | uniq -u
```

This almost works, but it doesn't give me the 2 fields that I cut. I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the size of the first file is not too big, an efficient solution is possible using Awk, and without sorting:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '
  NR == FNR {
    $1 = "";
    $2 = "";
    seen[$0]++;
 }
 NR != FNR {
   orig=$0;
   $1 = "";
   $2 = "";
   if (!seen[$0]) print orig
 }' today.txt new_today.txt`
```

As a one-liner: `awk -F'|' 'NR == FNR { $1 = ""; $2 = ""; seen[$0]++ } NR != FNR { orig=$0; $1 = ""; $2 = ""; if (!seen[$0]) print orig }' today.txt new_today.txt`

For the example input files this outputs:

> ```
> 934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
> 30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
> ```

Here's how it works:

- We pass two input files to the Awk script on the command line. This will be important.
- `-F'|'` -- use pipe as the field separator.
- Filter 1: `NR == FNR` -- this matches lines in the first input file.

  - We build a map of lines we've seen, without the first two fields.
    We do this by clearing the values of the first two fields (`$1`, `$2`), and using the rest (`$0`) as the key, and count it.
- Filter 2: `NR != FNR` -- this matches lines *not* in the first input file.

  - We save the original line, compute the key, and if we haven't seen it yet, then we print the original line.

Notice that this approach also preserves the original order of the lines in the second file.

Comment: Brilliant! Not only does it preserve the order, but it also gives the flexibility  to ignore whatever fields I want! Thank you.

Comment: This is definitely an effective method on small inputs. Note that `seen` stores the entirety of yesterday's data, which becomes a problem when that is too large to fit in memory. In that situation `sort`+`uniq` would continue to work reliably as `sort` uses temporary files when the input is large, and `uniq` has minimal memory requirements.

Comment: Good point @jhnc, a limitation worth mentioning, added to my answer, thanks!

Comment: An array named `seen[]` is idiomatically used to distinguish the first from subsequent appearances of it's index, e.g. `if ( !seen[$0]++ ) print "first time"`. Your array named `seen[]` isn't being used for that purpose, it's being used to identify whether or not the index from the 2nd file was present in the first file so it shouldn't be named `seen[]`. Also, doing `if (!seen[$0])` will unnecessarily grow the array for every line read from the second file. You should be using `NR==FNR{... first[$0]; next} .{.. if (!($0 in first)) ...}` instead.

Comment: You also have an insidious bug that'd cause a false match if the files contained blanks because after you do `$1=""` or `$2=""` all `|`s in `$0` will be converted to blanks as changing the value of a field causes $0 to be reconstructed replacing every `FS` with `OFS`. So if file1 contained `a|b|c|d e` and file2 contained `a|b|c d|e` then as soon as you do `$1=""; $2=""` you end up with `$0` from file1 containing `<2 blanks>c d e` and `$0` from file2 also containing `<2 blanks>c d e` so the code would treat them as identical even though they started out different. You need to add `-v OFS="|"`.

Answer (score 2):

### Reusing most of your code:

```
sort <(cut -d"|" -f3- yesterday.txt) \
     <(cut -d"|" -f3- today.txt) |
     uniq -u |
     xargs -I% grep '%' today.txt || true
```

### Output

```
30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
```

Comment: Fantastic! I think this will work great for my use case! thank you much. I'll have to do some research on the xargs to get a better understanding.

Comment: That would produce false matches for substrings and regexp metachars.

Comment: Thanks to report Ed, should be fixed now for substrings.

Comment: I might be misreading it but won't the output of `uniq -u |` be the last 3 fields from the input while `grep '^%$'` will be trying to match those 3 fields against all 5 fields? If I'm right you'd need `grep '|%$'` but then you'd still need to solve the regexp problem too (`a.c` matching `abc` for example). The usual "solution" is to add a call to `sed` to sanitize any regexp chars for `grep` or change `grep` to `awk` to do literal string comparisons.

Comment: Hey, I'm now out of the mindset of this answer. This is not perfect, but answer OP question.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'|' '{key=$3 FS $4 FS $5} NR==FNR{a[key]; next} !(key in a)' yesterday.txt today.txt
934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
```

Answer (score 1):

`uniq` doesn't have an option to ignore pipe-delimited fields otherwise it would be ideal. If you had space-delimited input you could just do:

```
sort -k3 yesterday.txt yesterday.txt today.txt |
uniq -f2 -u
```

However, we can easily make the input appropriately space-delimited if we swap spaces and pipes before running `uniq` and then swap them back afterwards:

```
sort -t'|' -k3 yesterday.txt yesterday.txt today.txt |
tr ' |' '| ' |
uniq -f2 -u |
tr ' |' '| '
```

which gives:

```
30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
```

Comment: Nice. I was unfamiliar with the tr command. unfortunately I failed to mention that my actual use case has spaces in some of the values, but this is still really good info.

Comment: @bbaldwin81 shouldn't matter, the `tr` replaces any spaces with pipes during the comparison - try it. The only problem would be if you had escaped pipes in one of the first two fields

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a right anti join.

[image]

There are a few ways.

With any awk:

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{f1[$3 FS $4 FS $5]++; next}
!f1[$3 FS $4 FS $5]' yesterday.txt today.txt
```

Prints:

```
934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
```

With GNU awk you can use the `join` function so you don't have to change if the number of fields change:

```
gawk -i join '{split($0,a,"|"); key=join(a,3,length(a),"|")}
FNR==NR{f1[key]; next}
!(key in f1)' yesterday.txt today.txt
# same output
```

With POSIX `join`:

```
join  -t'|' -v 2  -1 3 -2 3 -1 4 -2 4 -1 5 -2 5 -o "2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5" <(sort -t'|' -k3,5 yesterday.txt) <(sort -t'|' -k3,5 today.txt)
30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
```

With [mlr](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.9.0/)

```
mlr --csv --ifs '|' --ofs '|' --implicit-csv-header join -u -j 3,4,5 --ur --np -f yesterday.txt today.txt | sed 1d
934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
```

With Ruby:

```
ruby -F"\|" -lane 'BEGIN{f1=Set.new()}
if $.==$<.file.lineno then f1<<$F[2..].join("|"); next end
puts $_ unless f1.include?($F[2..].join("|")) ' yesterday.txt today.txt
934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the first two fields as `FS` and the rest as key `$2`

```
$ awk -F'(^[0-9]*[|][0-9]*[|])' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]; next} !($2 in a)' yesterday.txt today.txt
934|25|Jack|Blatt|prograbber
30495|89|Dave|Scratt|slobber
```

Comment: I forgot about that approach again. nice!